# Is there a way to load the ContentProvider's uri directly into a queryBuilder?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-source

In most cases of building a `ContentBuilder` you must register it in the manifest and provide the `authority` so it knows where to look for the db when you call `query()`.

We have an odd case. We are modifying the android source and wish for the OS itself to communicate with an app's database. So we built a `ContentProvider` *for the OS* to use. The only problem now is that there's nowhere to register this `ContentProvider` since there's no manifest in the OS.

Is there a way in our `query()` to simply pass the `uri` into the `querybuilder` so it knows where to look for the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create your own database where you can store all URIs to Content providers. Or maybe I did not understand you problem.